# Why enterprise github can't deliver payload to webhook with ssl secured?

Tags: ssl, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, git-webhooks

verified the certificate information of `https://jenkins.example.com/github-webhook` with https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/.

Github repeatedly says following

`We couldn’t deliver this payload: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates`

here is the screenshot of the message: 
[image]

Comment: You likely need to install the certificate on GitHub Enterprise https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.11/admin/articles/command-line-utilities/#ghe-ssl-ca-certificate-install

Answer (score 2):

Its very likely a missing CA cert in the certificate chain. Try the Qualys checker, and compare the CA chain report to the CA certs bundle provided by your cert provider. You may be missing an intermediate.

Comment: Post a verbose curl of your cert